# Generalising mean value theorem for integrals

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, proof-verification, proof-writing

I want to generalize mean value theorem for Riemann integrals to $\Bbb R^n$, but I do not know how to formulate it. Can someone please help me with formulating the theorem? I think I can prove it myself. I just could not find it anywhere, only on 2 dimensions

Answer (score 0):

If

$$G : D \subset \mathbb{R}^n  \to \mathbb{R} $$

is a continuous function on convex domain D and $\varphi$ is an integrable function that does not change sign on the D, then there exists a point $C=(c_1,c_2,...,c_n)\in D$ such that

$$\int_{D} G(x_1,...,x_n)\varphi (x_1,...,x_n) dx_1dx_2...dx_n $$

$$=G(C) \int_D \varphi (x_1,...,x_n)dx_1dx_2...dx_n$$

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this?